# Cannot complete 200% of the map? Castlevania SOTN

Tags: castlevania-symphony-of-the-night

I'm not being able to complete 100% of the inverted castle in the area where we find the oarsman. Even using the high jump in the inverted water is useless. Is there another way to discover these areas?

## sotn #castlevania

[image: areas where I can't complete]

Comment: My question is not duplicated. The question which mine has been associated is not the same... I'm asking how I can complete the missing parts of the mark marked in orange, the other question is showing both inverted and non-inverted maps

Comment: Just for the record, I discoverd how we can complete those areas. Just do a high jump and once Alucard reaches de top, transform into wolf... This will do the trick
You guys don't read the question before closing it... Very disappointing